# Looping through entire table makes problem with showing multiple values to an single element

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, razor-pages

I have little problem with dynamically add data to the HTML from SQL Table..

This is my loop

```
@foreach (var item in Model.ModulesSubStages)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"><a id="courseRedirect" asp-page="/Site/Courses/@item.ModuleId/@item.Id" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"> @item.StageName </a></div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @foreach (var monit in Model.ProgressMonitor)
            {
                if (monit.UserId == Model._User.Id && item.Id == monit.CourseSubStageId)
                {
                    <i class="bi bi-check-circle-fill" id="@item.Id" style="color:green;"></i>
                }
                else if (monit.UserId == Model._User.Id && item.Id != monit.CourseSubStageId)
                {
                    <i class="bi bi-check-circle-fill" id="@item.Id" style="color:gray;"></i>
                }
                else
                {
                    <i class="bi bi-check-circle-fill" id="@item.Id" style="color:gray;"></i>
                }
            }
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**ModulesSubStages = 9 items**

**ProgressMonitor - table when i insert data after completing some action**

**Problem:**

This loop result is:

[image]

I want to loop through entire table and mark green if it is completed, else gray, i dont want to print to the html multiple values per 1 record.

-- UPDATE

this is ProgressMonitor table structure:

```
SELECT [Id]
      ,[CourseId]
      ,[CourseStageId]
      ,[CourseSubStageId]
      ,[UserId]
  FROM [ProgressMonitor];
```

Comment: There is no point in making the distinction between two cases just to do the same in both cases (`else if` and `else`).

Comment: yes i deleted else and none happened!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to secound loop!

you just use a where clause instead

```
@foreach (var item in Model.ModulesSubStages)
{
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"><a id="courseRedirect" asp-page="/Site/Courses/@item.ModuleId/@item.Id" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"> @item.StageName </a></div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @if (Model.ProgressMonitor.Any(a => a.UserId = Model._User.Id && item.Id == a.CourseSubStageId))
        {
            <i class="bi bi-check-circle-fill" id="@item.Id" style="color:green;"></i>
        }
        else
        {
            <i class="bi bi-check-circle-fill" id="@item.Id" style="color:gray;"></i>
        }
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your codes as below;

```
@foreach (var item in Model.ModulesSubStages){
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6"><a id="courseRedirect" asp-page="/Site/Courses/@item.ModuleId/@item.Id" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"> @item.StageName </a></div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    @foreach (var monit in Model.ProgressMonitor)
    {
        if (monit.UserId == Model._User.Id )
        {
         if (item.Id == monit.CourseSubStageId )
           {
            <i class="bi bi-check-circle-fill" id="@item.Id" style="color:green;"></i>
           {
              break;
             }
           }
         else if (item.Id != monit.CourseSubStageId )
            {
            <i class="bi bi-check-circle-fill" id="@item.Id" style="color:gray;"></i>
             {
              break;
             }
            }
        }
        
    }
   </div>
  </div>
}
```

Comment: Hello, after deleting this none happen. If i change this:      else if (monit.UserId == Model._User.Id)
     {
      <i class="bi bi-check-circle-fill" id="@item.Id" style="color:gray;display:none;"></i>
     }
i can see only green, but if 8/9 elements are completed, 9 is not marked as gray :) https://imgur.com/tmjIEOV

Comment: first, you foreach all items for draw html, then you foreach all items for read status. maybe you not correct compare ? can you share json data? if possible

Comment: There is no json data, this is data from SQL table as i mention in first post. 

This is table structure:

SELECT [Id]
      ,[CourseId]
      ,[CourseStageId]
      ,[CourseSubStageId]
      ,[UserId]
  FROM [ProgressMonitor];

Comment: @SoftwareArchitect I update my solition. Use it.

Comment: @cancan still the same result :/ All markups are shown

Comment: @SoftwareArchitect I update else block. Try it too please.

Comment: @cancan https://imgur.com/Kx5t4Iz - first 9 items is old loop, second 9 items is your loop. Idk why this is showing false result :D

Comment: Hot it would be ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249765/discussion-between-software-architect-and-cancan).